# Extract value from inner attribute of Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flexslider

I am learning web development and this is my first questions. Sorry if I ask in unstructured manner.

I am using flexslider in my project and I want to extract some values from slider.

```
<ul class="position-list slides background-white">
    <li id="172" class="slide pointer season-selector active" data-short-year="17" data-short-desc="FW17"></li>
    <li id="173" class="slide pointer season-selector active" data-short-year="18" data-short-desc="SS18"></li>
```

I want to get `data-short-desc` values. I tried `.find` to get values but it doesn't work.

```
$(".position-list").find('data-short-year').val();
```

Is there any way to get those values?

Comment: Under what event do you want to get those values?

Comment: I get a JSON and then on the value I get, I am trying to sort them.

Comment: So you want to sort the `li` elements based on the `data-short-year` value?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. That is what I am trying.

Comment: I added an answer for you, that shows how to sort elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get a JSON and then on the value I get, I am trying to sort them

This is different to the title of your question. To achieve this you can use the `sort()` method:

```js
$('.position-list li').sort(function(a, b) {
  return $(a).data('short-year') > $(b).data('short-year');
}).appendTo('.position-list');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="position-list slides background-white">
  <li id="173" class="slide pointer season-selector active" data-short-year="18" data-short-desc="SS18">
    SS18 - 18
  </li>
  <li id="172" class="slide pointer season-selector active" data-short-year="12" data-short-desc="Bar12">
    Bar - 12
  </li>
  <li id="172" class="slide pointer season-selector active" data-short-year="10" data-short-desc="Foo10">
    Foo - 10
  </li>
  <li id="172" class="slide pointer season-selector active" data-short-year="17" data-short-desc="FW17">
    FW17 - 17
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try following:-

```
$('.position-list li').each(function(){
var short_year = $(this).data('short-year');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`data-short-year` is an attribute, not an element.

You need an attribute selector: `.find('[data-short-year]')`

Then you are looking to get the content of the attribute, not the current value of a form control.

Normally, you would use `attr()`, but `data-*` is special: `.data('short-year')`.